# Error 1236 From Master After Restored Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, error-handling, percona-server

I've been trying to restore a broken replication caused by power interruption. upon checking the **slaveDB**, it was already broken so I setup a new replication. And upon supposedly completing the replication, i'm stuck with this: **Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log:    'Misconfigured master - server id was not set'**

We are running Percona Server 5.5.
Here were the procedures i made:

1.) on the Master Server **masterDB** (IP = 10.0.0.20, server_id = 1),I ran innobackupex to make a hot backup. checked the xtrabackup_binlog_info and noted *slavedb-bin.000609*    and *113535960* as the binlog file and position.

2.) Restored the backup to the **slaveDB** (IP = 10.0.0.40), and setup the replication as follows -- **CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='10.0.0.20', MASTER_USER='user',MASTER_PASSWORD='password',MASTER_LOG_FILE='slavedb-bin.000609',MASTER_LOG_POS=113535960** (as noted from the xtrabackup_binlog_info from the innobackupex backup.

3.) After Starting the Slave, i get the error 1236 above with a misconfigured master, but the master server_id is 1.

I've read online on an old thread that a possible solution would be to go to the next binlog file since it might have been corrupted with the transactions applied.

But how would i go about moving to the next binlog file? Is it the **next binlog from the innobackupex xtrabackup_binlog_info?"** or should i check the master log and find out the last binlog written before it crashed?

I tried moving past the binlog from what innobackupex gave me, going to slavedb-bin.000610 and POS=0, but it still got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a guess, but please note that **the option `server-id` cannot be activated in a hot way**. In my experience, this is a common cause of problems when setting up the replication for the first time, specially because **the master accepts the following syntax without complaining**:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL server_id = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
```

And the server id seems to have taken effect:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'server\_id';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| server_id     | 1     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

But **it doesn't work**, (it does not have effect until restart and read from the `my.cnf` or passed as a parameter). **The slave will complain until the master is restarted.**

The official documentation is misleading, [while it says it is dynamic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options.html#option_mysqld_server-id) in reality it is not (or at least it is not when setup for the first time, or setup with the default, etc.). See [this bug for details](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56739), mentioning the misleading documentation.

In summary, activation of the binary logs and server id setup requires a server restart, so I always recommend to do it on installation time. Change it on the `[mysqld]`section of your configuration file and restart the service.

Comment: following your commend about the server-id.. i actually tried setting it dynamically via mysql CLI using _set global server_id=xxx_ , and after setting it, going back to the slave and setting up the master again it finally worked! i guess the binlog bug really did affect our server.